# Multibinding with combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 ComboBox, 1 textBox and 1 button, the button have multibinding to pass the value of the combox´s and tthe textbox, but 1 of the combobox is filled with an Objec that i created and have a DataTemplate to only show 1 of the properties of the object i created. When i obtain in the ViewModel the values Works fine for the combox that is filled with strings and with the texBox, but when i inspect the value of the other combox returns me a string with the name of the object i created.

What am I supposed to do to get the property(Id) of the object, and not the name?

The XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,59,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding _combo}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Situación: "></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nombre}" Width="80"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>

    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="573,66,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=multiDateConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="textBox" Path="Text"></Binding>
                <Binding ElementName="comboBox" Path="Text"></Binding>
                <Binding ElementName="comboBox1" Path="Text"></Binding>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
        <Button.Command>
            <Binding Path="GetAllActionLogsBetweenDatesCommand"></Binding>
        </Button.Command>
    </Button>
```

This is the object code

```
 namespace PedidosRetraso.Model
{
    class PocoCombo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
    class Prueba: PocoCombo
    {

    }
}
```

The ViewModel code:

```
class ViewModelMain 
    {
        public ICommand GetAllActionLogsBetweenDatesCommand { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<PocoCombo> _combo { get; set; }


        public ViewModelMain()
        {
            GetAllActionLogsBetweenDatesCommand = new RelayCommand(GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates_Execute);

            _combo = new ObservableCollection<PocoCombo> { new PocoCombo { Id = 20, Nombre = "Enviado" }, new PocoCombo { Id = 25, Nombre = "DIF" }, new PocoCombo { Id = 30, Nombre = "Confirmado" }, new PocoCombo { Id = 40, Nombre = "RP" }, new PocoCombo { Id = 50, Nombre = "Cerrado" }, new PocoCombo { Id = 60, Nombre = "C" } };
        }

  private void GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates_Execute(object parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            var stringList = parameter as string[];

            string proveedor = stringList[0];
            string empresa = stringList[1];
            string situacion = stringList[2];
            DateTime fecha = DateTime.Parse(stringList[3]);
            // Aqui la consulta SQL
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And finally the converter:

```
public class ICommandMultiDateConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        PocoCombo p = new PocoCombo();
        //p = (PocoCombo)values[2];
        return new string[] { values[0].ToString(), values[1].ToString(), values[2].ToString(),values[3].ToString() };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the binding:

```
<Binding ElementName="comboBox1" Path="SelectedItem.Id" />
```

The selected item in the ComboBox is an instance of `PocoCombo`. You want the `Id` property from that instance -- there it is.

Also, it would be a good idea to rename `_combo` to `Combo`. A lower-case name prefixed with an underscore is universally understood to mean that it's a private field. To avoid confusion, a public property should be named in "PascalCase": `Combo` in this case. The mistake won't break your code, but fixing it will make your code easier for people to understand.

Comment: Yes,  i read about the private is lower-case and public whith upper-Case, but i don´t know why i was thinking it was private,, today is not my day.. Thanks for the answer, Works perfect.